# How to convert a data frame / tibble into named list of vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(seq_name = c("Peptide_set1.r1", "Peptide_set2.r1"
), peptide = c("KSKLRHGC", "AAYVYVNQF"
)), .Names = c("seq_name", "peptide"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

dat
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   seq_name        peptide  
#>   <chr>           <chr>    
#> 1 Peptide_set1.r1 KSKLRHGC 
#> 2 Peptide_set2.r1 AAYVYVNQF
```

What I want to do is to convert them into this list of vector:

```r
$Peptide_set1.r1
[1] "K" "S" "K" "L" "R" "H" "G" "C"


$Peptide_set2.r1
[[1] "A" "A" "Y" "V" "Y" "V" "N" "Q" "F"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. But not quite. I need the **named** list.

Comment: @RonakShah No. The name should be taken from `seq-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the strings at each character using `strsplit` and assign names using `setnames`

```
setNames(strsplit(dat$peptide, ""), dat$seq_name)

#$Peptide_set1.r1
#[1] "K" "S" "K" "L" "R" "H" "G" "C"

#$Peptide_set2.r1
#[1] "A" "A" "Y" "V" "Y" "V" "N" "Q" "F"
```

---

To use column index instead of names we can use `pull` to convert column values to vector as this is a tibble

```
library(dplyr)
setNames(strsplit(pull(dat[2]), ""), pull(dat[1]))

#$Peptide_set1.r1
#[1] "K" "S" "K" "L" "R" "H" "G" "C"

#$Peptide_set2.r1
#[1] "A" "A" "Y" "V" "Y" "V" "N" "Q" "F"
```

---

We can add them completely into `dplyr` chain operation as well

```
library(tidyverse)
dat1 <- dat %>% mutate(new = setNames(strsplit(pull(dat[2]), ""), pull(dat[1])))

dat1$new
#$Peptide_set1.r1
#[1] "K" "S" "K" "L" "R" "H" "G" "C"

#$Peptide_set2.r1
#[1] "A" "A" "Y" "V" "Y" "V" "N" "Q" "F"
```

---

And as @thelatemail commented, we can extract the columns using `[[` instead of `pull`

```
setNames(strsplit(dat[[2]], ""), dat[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I modify your code so that it takes the column index instead of name e.g. instead of `dat$peptide` or `dat$seq_name`. I tried this but failed `setNames(strsplit(as.list(dat[1]), ""), dat[2,])`

Comment: `setNames(strsplit(dat[[2]], ""), dat[[1]])` works too given that `[[` is the R primitive operation for extracting from lists, which a `tbl` still is under all these layers.  `pull` is supposed to replace `[[` so the syntax should actually be `pull(dat, 2)` otherwise you're invoking `[` then `[[`.

Comment: @thelatemail I forgot about `[[`, thanks for explanation on `pull` as well. :)